Open international .csv files gives different output
my little sub should open raw data files (*.csv) in order to convert them later somehow:
Sub OpenRawData()
 
    Dim wsraw As Worksheet
    Dim rawdatafile As String
    
    rawdatafile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv*),*.csv*")
    
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=rawdatafile, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Semicolon:=True
    
    Set wsraw = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

End Sub

The raw data comes from different instruments (USA and GER).
Opening the USA file works well and looks like this:
RawData2_USA -each row in column "A"
Opening the GER file gives me this:
RawData1_GER - automatically uses comma as separator
Opening both files in the windows editor looks like this:
(RawData in editor)
How can I prevent Excel from producing different outputs?
Or how can I ensure that I get the same output regardless of which raw data file I open?
I tried a different method: (Workbooks Open instead of Workbooks OpenText)
and I tried different parameter. No matter which separator I use, the GER file uses comma as separator

Don't Open.  Using either Power Query or the Legacy Wizard, you should Import the csv files so you can deal with that problem. Plenty of examples exist on this forum.

You could try to explicitly set Comma:=False (although this should already be the default) to explicitly disable the , as column separator.
But even then, you will run into problems, because for parsing numbers Excel uses the DecimalSeparator from the current system's locale. Thus, if you have CSV files with different decimal separators (. in the US version and , in the GER version, ie 59.80 vs 69,91 from your examples) you will always end up with different results unless you set the DecimalSeparator:=... explicitly when opening the file, depending on where you are located. Ie, on a "german" machine, 59.80 won't be recognized and on a "us" machine 69,91 won't be recognized. But for that, you will have to distinguish where the file originates.
If there is any chance, you should try to standardize the CSV generation process, ie all CSV files should use the same column separators as well as the same number format.

I also tried the explicit false case. no change. but your explanation helps. I'll try to standardize, sounds easier

The reason can be found here: How to change Excel CSV delimiter to comma or semicolon. There you can find a solution to your problem. You can either force the specific Windows machine to use different separator or change your program to work with all separators that can appear in your CSV files.
Citation from that page:

Microsoft Excel uses the List separator defined in Windows Regional
settings.  In North America and some other countries, the default
list separator is a comma, so you get CSV comma delimited. In European
countries, a comma is reserved for the decimal symbol, and the list
separator is generally set to semicolon. That is why the result is CSV
semicolon delimited.


It would be arguably better to convert the files properly at the time, instead of first opening them and then converting them later.
To do that you should be using either the Legacy Import Wizard or Power Query, both of which enable you to specify the relevant separators, decimals, date format and other variables at the time of import.
You can access Power Query via Data=>Get&Transform=>from text/csv. If you need it in VBA, just record a macro while you do that -- it should be obvious how to make the needed modifications for your actual case.
If, for some reason, you really want to have the entire contents laid out in column A, row by row and not separated, then I suggest you use the FileSystemObject as it would be simpler.
eg:
'Set referencet to Microsoft Scripting runtime
' or use late-binding if you prefer
Option Explicit
Sub OpenRawData()
 
    Dim wsraw As Worksheet
    Dim rawdatafile As Variant
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim V As Variant
    
Set wsraw = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    rawdatafile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv*),*.csv*")

If Not rawdatafile = False Then
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(rawdatafile)
    V = Split(ts.ReadAll, vbNewLine)

    With wsraw.Cells(1, 1)
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Resize(rowsize:=UBound(V) + 1).Value = V
    End With
End If
    
End Sub

